# jboss stopped inbetween execute query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jboss

My application is suddenly stopped while executing any queries on jboss. then I pressed `ctrl+c` once time so it will execute further queries.

This things happen uncertainly and I could not get conclusion that what is really problem in it?

I am using jboss 7 , hibernate criteria  and sql server. and when I see the console output of jboss then I found Hibernate criteria is generated very big query statement. but it is working perfect in development.

How can I get to know that the problem is with jboss, sql server or hibernate criteria?

And is this really problem with hibernate then is there any process to major the query performance in hibernate before execute? I mean to ask before executing generated hibernate  criteria query can I track queries through any api?

Also is there any rules for queries length?
or can we check is there any query problem before execution?

Comment: Sounds like it may be a deadlock. What database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use kill -3 on the java process to get a thread dump and see if there is a way you encounter a dead lock.
there is a way for hibernate to use outer join instead of separated queries, that could help you.